# Get innerHTML via clicking on a div tag in vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want to get a number between a `div` tag that is generated via `v-for` attribute in vue3 when `click` event happens. How to do that ?

```html
<template>
    <div @click="doSth" class="days" v-for="n in 7" :key="n">{{n}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    methods : {
       doSth() {
           // get {{n}} from inside a div tag when clicking on it and do something on it.
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just catch the event target in the method and do what you want on text content :

```html
<template>
    <div @click="doSth" class="days" v-for="n in 7" :key="n">{{n}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    methods: {
        doSth(event) {
            // Let says that you want to add 10 to the "n" number displayed in the div you clicked on :
            event.target.textContent = parseInt(event.target.textContent) + 10;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
<div @click="doSth(n)" class="days" v-for="n in 7" :key="n">{{n}}</div>
```

```js
methods : {
   doSth(n) {
       console.log(n)
   }
}
```